# ASP.Net MVC Cookieless Session - SessionID Missing from Request.Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, session, httprequest

Im using MVC with cookieless sessions to implement different displays per monitor.  So, the session is working correctly and I can see the SessionID in the URL in the browser.  But I want to automatically refresh the page using an AJAX call.  My ajax call uses Request.Url as it's url to refresh.  However, the SessionID is not in the Request.Url so it is creating a new session.  How do I get the full URL with SessionID as seen in browser like this:

```
(http://localhost:56553/(S(ub14lfb0xq5e3ehmyevpk5mh))/OVERVIEW)
```

Comment: ASP.NET MVC does not support cookieless sessions. I'm curious to learn how you enabled this 'feature'. I'll note that you don't necessarily need cookieless sessions to enable per-window identification, you could do that with any other kind of parameter sent in the URI.

Comment: Just inhe  the web.config set it to UseURI.  The SessionID is in the URI.

Comment: @Dai "I'll note that you don't necessarily need cookieless sessions to enable per-window identification, you could do that with any other kind of parameter sent in the URI" Do you have an literature to support this - I am looking for this exact solution.

Comment: Response.ApplyAppPathModifier

Answer (score 2):

I ended up just rebuilding my refresh url as follows and it works.  If there's a better way I'd love to hear it.

```
@Request.Url.Scheme://@Request.Url.Authority/(S(@Session.SessionID))@Request.RawUrl
```